# pptx add new slide.xml giving relationship problems

Tags: xml, ms-office, powerpoint

I am doing automatic text generation from a Microsoft powerpoint presentation and then write back the text to new powerpoint presentation.

I have done the generation of the text successfully and also part of writing back the text to a new pptx as well. But now I need to add a new slide into the new presentation manually and when i extract the pptx, I find a folder called slides and I added the new slide (slide35.xml) in there and zipped it back to pptx, but I dont find the new slide. Then after a Google explore I found that there are relationships and references inside the folder something like  presentation.rels folder which has the reference to the slides.  Can any1 suggest me how could I add a new slide and what changes I have to make to the other files in the unzipped pptx folder to do it successfully?? I am kind of stuck here. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

I am not using Open XML.sdk!!!!

Comment: Have you tried letting PowerPoint add a new slide, then looking at the rels "file" to see what it did there?

Comment: Yes sure but I found the ref ids along with the slide path...So when i add a new slide "slide.xml" to extracted path ".../ppt/slides/slide.xml" I also tried to find out where these reference ids actually are referred to.. COuld you please tell me if there is any documentation which explains this or if u have some info on this, please share. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good starting point:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Well thats what i wanted ..cheers...I wonder how i couldnt find it ..hmmm anyways thank you